# url gets cropped before reaching maximum lenght with serialize/php arrays

Tags: php, html

I am learning php. I have some code where I am trying to post 2 variables and 2 arrays from one php page to another page, the recieving page works fine but the first page is cropping data after a few characters (it hasnt reached max lenght or anywhere close)-

Here, $array_name and $array_qty are two dynamic arrays. I have verified that echo $c gives me exactly what I want.

```
 <?php
  $serialized_name=serialize($array_name);
  $serialized_qty=serialize($array_qty) ;
  $c="count=".$count ."&&Sum=" . $a . "&&serialized_name=". $serialized_name . "&&serialized_qty=". $serialized_qty;
  echo $c;
  ?>
```

echo $c gives me-

```
 count=6&&Sum=45.91&&serialized_name=a:7:{i:0;s:7:"vanilla";i:1;s:7:"vanilla";i:2;s:21:"very berry strawberry";i:3;s:7:"vanilla";i:4;s:7:"vanilla";i:5;s:7:"vanilla";i:6;s:7:"vanilla";}&&serialized_qty=a:7:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;s:1:"1";i:3;s:1:"1";i:4;s:1:"1";i:5;s:1:"3";i:6;s:1:"3";}
```

However, this gives me cropped output of `$c=`

```
 <p><a href="Checkout.php?<?php echo $c ?>" >Checkout</a> </p>
```

The cropped output that i get from the above line is-

```
http://localhost/myRestaurant/Checkout.php?count=6&&Sum=45.91&&serialized_name=a:7:{i:0;s:7:
```

I think I should have gotten this-

```
http://localhost/myRestaurant/Checkout.php?count=6&&Sum=45.91&&serialized_name=a:7:{i:0;s:7:%22vanilla%22;i:1;s:7:%22vanilla%22;i:2;s:21:%22very%20berry%20strawberry%22;i:3;s:7:%22vanilla%22;i:4;s:7:%22vanilla%22;i:5;s:7:%22vanilla%22;i:6;s:7:%22vanilla%22;}&&serialized_qty=a:7:{i:0;s:1:%222%22;i:1;s:1:%221%22;i:2;s:1:%221%22;i:3;s:1:%221%22;i:4;s:1:%221%22;i:5;s:1:%223%22;i:6;s:1:%223%22;}
```

I know get is not the best most secure way but I think this should have worked. Any tips on what I am doing wrong and how to fix it will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `&&` to separate your parameters in the URL? it should be just `&`

Comment: ok, I am learning html, I will try that.

Comment: Have you tried to urlencode the string? echo urlencode($c)

Comment: i tried urlencode and that did not work, perhaps i did not use it properly. Anyway waleed's suggestion of using htmlentities works for me!

Comment: **WARNING!** Passing PHP serialized values in URLs is *amazingly insecure*.  The processing of unserializing can result in arbitrary code execution.  You should *never* accept serialized data from users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quotation mark will end the attribute prematurely. Escape your quotation marks:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($c); ?>
```

Comment: They should escape each url parameter and value individually using php's `urlencode` in addition to using html entities

Answer (score 1):

You should use POST for that kind of shopping cart product, but anyway, if you want to just create a URL out of your arrays, you can't just serialize arbitrary data, you'll need to encode the data or it will break because of special chars.

Just use for encoding:

```
$serialized_name = base64_encode(serialize($array_name));
$serialized_qty = base64_encode(serialize($array_qty));
```

For retrieveing the data, in Checkout.php, do the opposite:

```
$unserialized_name = unserialize(base64_decode($_GET["serialized_name"]));
$unserialized_qty = unserialize(base64_decode($_GET["serialized_qty"]));
```